# Ninject in ASP.NET MVC and on the web in general

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

When using Ninject in an ASP.NET MVC application, is the kernel shared among concurrent users on your website? Is it possible to create a conditional binding so that different users get different concrete implementations of the same Interface something like this...

```
 if (user == "A")
      kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<FooForA>();
 else
      kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<FooForB>();
```

without conflict arising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the kernel shared among concurrent users on your website?

In a typical (and recommended) setup, you have one instance of the `Kernel` per AppDomain. This means that every request (and thus every user) accesses the same `Kernel` instance (and possibly in parallel).

> Is it possible to create a conditional binding so that different users get different concrete implementations of the same Interface something like this...

It is not recommended to base the construction of an object graph based on runtime data (your `user == "A"` is decision based on runtime data `user`). This exposes the same downsides as [injecting runtime data into application composents](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) does:

> it causes ambiguity, complicates the composition root with an extra responsibility and makes it extraordinarily hard to verify the correctness of your DI configuration.

Instead, the advice is to:

> to let runtime data flow through the method calls of constructed object graphs.

You can achieve this simply and elegantly by introducing a proxy for `IFoo` that forwards any incoming call to either `FooForA` or `FooForB`, based on the runtime data. For instance:

```
public sealed class FooSelectorProxy : IFoo
{
    private readonly FooForA afoo;
    private readonly FooForB bfoo;
    public FooSelectorProxy(FooForA afoo, FooForB bfoo) {
        this.afoo = afoo;
        this.bfoo = bfoo;
    }

    public object FooMethod(object args) {
        return CurrentFoo.FooMethod(args);
    }

    private IFoo CurrentFoo {
        get { return user == "A" ? this.afoo : this.bfoo; }
    }
}
```

Using this `FooSelectorProxy`, you can make the following registration:

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<FooSelectorProxy>();
```

This postpones the execution of the `if (user == "A")` code until *after* the construction of the object graph until the moment that runtime data is available.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks very much for your help.